# angularjs factory service error

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am getting this error

```
...([c,d,arguments]);return k}}if(!e)throw Error("No module: "+d);var b=[],c=[],j=a...
```

can anyone please help on this issue.

```
<div ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="booksCtrl">
            <div ng-repeat="book in allBooks">
                <ul>
                    <li>{{book.title}}</li>
                    <li>{{book.author}}</li>
                    <li>{{book.year}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

..............................

```
(function(){

    angular.module('app').factory('dataService', dataService);

    function dataService(){
        return {
            getAllBooks : getAllBooks,
        };

        function getAllBooks(){
            return[
                {
                    book_id:1,
                    title:"hari potter",
                    author:"J.K. Rowling",
                    year:2009
                },
                {
                    book_id:2,
                    title:"The Cat in the Hat",
                    author : "DR. Seuss",
                    year : 1967
                },
                {
                    book_id:3,
                    title:"Encyclopedia",
                    author : "Donald j Sobol",
                    year : 1940
                }
            ];

        };
    };



}());


(function(){

    angular.module('app').controller('booksCtrl', booksCtrl);

    function booksCtrl($scope, dataService){
        $scope.allBooks = dataService.getAllBooks();
    }

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not initialized module app. You have to initialized your module once using syntax

```
angular.module('app', [])
```

in any one of js file.

```
(function(){

angular.module('app',[]).controller('booksCtrl', booksCtrl);
function booksCtrl($scope, dataService){
 $scope.allBooks = dataService.getAllBooks();
}
}());
```

from official documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

> Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.